# Is there an equivalent to jTable component for Bootstrap?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-jtable

I am looking for something similar to jTable component that is written by jQuery and bootstrap. This is a link to jTable website:

http://www.jtable.org

Comment: Have you find anything?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> - http://datatables.net/ 
>     has it's own implementation of bootstrap http://datatables.net/manual/styling/bootstrap
> - [jTable & Bootstrap](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/679647/jTable-Bootstrap) read more at https://github.com/hikalkan/jtable/pull/956

Comment: I've seen jTable & bootstrap project on github, but it seems that it needs some more work. But datatables seems promising, thank you :)